# trying to determining if an object's "inner" property exists

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have come up with a solution is there is any better approach to solve this in JavaScript

```
if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
  console.log(error.response.data.error);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, Something went wrong!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, that's how you do it.

At some point, the [optional chaining proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) may progress. Using the syntax from that proposal, you'd be able to write this:

```
// NOT VALID SYNTAX YET (A STAGE 2 PROPOSAL)
if (error.response?.data?.error) {
  console.log(error.response.data.error);
} else {
  console.log('Sorry, Something went wrong!');
}
```

You can use that syntax today if you transpile with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and use the `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` plugin.

[Live Example on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=PTAEAoBkHtoa1ASwHagC4AsCmoDG1kBnaAGywEoAoSgMwFdlc1EDQsAPAQwFsAHM8FgBOQ6EPKgA3pVCgQoAHIB5ACqgAagEFIASQAioAMoBNBSs0ANUMYCia8JqPmA4jdAAmUAAUASkq9KhtpUsog0EMKiQgB0QliEvASEWAD80QAmnGicaZFiEtKyRXhJpFjRJNAA5oIiYrHxiUTlmdnReeIA3DKgAL5sJMlSPcX4RGUV1eAA5IZiQgCeADRG0NxYmChVoADuWMhou6LIVQCE0-Tdsr2UN_Iq2EOYcTiEGNA76NigAETEIgsfqB1oRCJwqlhKBwePwsOBJL1LlCuHwBJI4gkklgAFxSXqI7rQ1Fw9GNLG4yStTgU_EEyj3DCIQigAivd47ZmYHAdYHxMEQ5EwtEYprJClUikdXE_B5MpCc748kH8rA_WmXIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-proposal-optional-chaining%407.2.0)